# unqualifed id error iOS

Tags: c++, iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to compile an Xcode project and I am receiving a bunch of unwanted errors such as this

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/i PhoneSimulator6.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObject.h:13:1: error: expected unqualified-id
```

The project works fine, but when I try to include this file "iRate.h" in my app delegate everything goes wrong. The app delegate class I am trying to include iRate is written in c++(cpp file). I don't know what other information you might need, but that pretty much sums it all up

Here is another error message, hopefully this will help out a bit

```
  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:418:50: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
  FOUNDATION_EXPORT Protocol *NSProtocolFromString(NSString *namestr) NS_AVAILABLE(10_5, 2_0);
                                             ^
                                     ^
```

Comment: Are your Objective-C files named with a `.mm` file extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are mixing C++ with Objective-C, you need to give your file the .mm file extension.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the c++ files in objective c, you need to have your objective-c files extension as .mm (obj-c++) instead of just .m (obj-c), have you tried that?

Comment: Yes, Irate has an extension of .mm, but it still doesn't work sadly.

Comment: hmm if its not recognising NSString then something fundamentally must be missing, check that you have all the default frameworks present and stuff. seems like a really weird problem

Answer (score 0):

Check the very beginning and end of all your header and code files. Start with the first lines of all headers. I mean line number 1, where usually the comments are that you never look at. You might find one of them with a stray character or so just before the comment starts with //.

```
d// Copyright ...
```

(In my case it was a d because I have the habit of having the left middle finger on the d when I do nothing but thinking or so.)

Unfortunately you cannot tell which of the header files causes it. And it may well be a stray character at some implmentation or some interface end.

```
@end
d
```

Good luck!